# What is the best probabilistic graphical model toolkit for MATLAB?

Tags: data-visualization, graphical-model

I want to use the Probabilistic graphical model toolkit for my research. (preferably MATLAB based).

There seems to be pretty a lot of different toolkits available online (UGM, Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab, PMTK:probabilistic modeling toolkit for Matlab/Octave,Mens X Machina Probabilistic Graphical Model Toolbox (PGM Toolbox)).

Could you recommend 1) the most popular and widely used toolkit for PGMs and 2) the easiest toolkit with demos that I can gain some hands-on exposure?

Thanks!

Comment: BNT has good demos and is easy to use. PMTK is developed by the same person so it probably has considerable overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having same question of yours for my upcoming research usage. 
You may find the following link useful where all existing tools are summarized:

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/pmtk/pmtk2/PMTK2-lci-may09.pdf

I am personally planning to use the PMTK tool.

Hope it may help.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Could you summarize the main points of the reference you provided? In case of link rot, that might be useful for future readers of this thread.